# Resizeable tab area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted a resizeable selector on my tabs in the page so i used Jquery UI resizeable component. But i'm facing issues in finding out the number of tabs selected and so on.

Note : The div can be resized from both the ends.

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/svXTa/10/

**Is there any jquery plugin which can provide me with this kind of functionality?**

Answer (score 0):

```
var enw = parseInt(Math.abs(newWidth / gridSize));
```

EDIT:

I'm back with a new update. Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svXTa/14/)

```
var tabs = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.dateTab ul li').each(function(){
        var tabNo = parseInt($(this).html(),10);
        tabs.push({'no':tabNo, 'right':tabNo * ($(this).width() + 2)});
    });

    $('#dDragHandler').resizable({
        handles: 'e,w' ,
        grid: [32,32],
        distance: 28,
        maxWidth: 940,
        minWidth: 0,    
        resize: function(event, ui) {
                   },
        stop : function(event, ui) {

        var pos = $('.dateDragHandler').offset();
        var width  = $('.dateDragHandler').width()+1;
        var right = pos.right + width;

            var html = "Number of tabs selected: " + parseInt(width / 32, 10);


        for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            if(tabs[i].right == pos.left) {
                html += "<br />First tab selected is: " + tabs[i + 1].no;
            }
            if(tabs[i].right == right) {
                html += "<br />Latest tab selected is: " + tabs[i].no;
            }
        }
        $('.dateInfoTab').html(html);

    }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes that is correct i'm using that to find the number of tabs selected.

Comment: When I added that to the fiddle, it seems to select one less than the number the cursor is hovering over, rather than the selected number of tabs. http://jsfiddle.net/svXTa/11/ I'm using chrome.

Comment: yes the logic used is not perfect and so sometimes it shows lesser value due to this inconsistency i'm also not able to find the specific tabs selected like..2,3,4,5.. etc

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that this will be the needed solution